# Are there websites like youtube with html5 that work over Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

On which sites like youtube can I watch videos in html5 over Tor? How can I make downloads with TBB of videos that do not support html5?

I want to see videos at vimeo.com but unable to so with TBB.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.savefrom.net/ works well for youtube content that doesn't have an HTML5 version, this site seems to convert the download to an MP4 rather than a FLV as well. I would imagine it would work with Vimeo too but haven't tried.

Answer (score 2):

What Vimeo needs is the H.264 codec on you machine and you have to enable that on Firefox.

I assume you are using TBB with Firefox 24 on Linux, as by default Windows 7 supports h264, Win XP will not be supported.

These steps work on TBB/Firefox/Iceweasel -> [Firefox now with h264 on Linux](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM5NzU)
Quoting from it

> ..the `media.gstreamer.enabled` preference can be enabled via `about:config`. Aside from enabling the option in Firefox, the GStreamer libraries must be installed on the system."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[Alpha-7-Bravo-Blog (Tor hidden service)](http://opnju4nyz7wbypme.onion/weblog) has several interesting pages of html5 video and is always adding more. Most of the content is encoded at 128k/s or 256k/s so the tor network can provide a reasonable transport.